# French equivalent of the Japanese expression 火事場の馬鹿力, « une force ridiculement surhumaine dont on fait preuve dans un incendie »

Tags: expressions

On utilise cette expression pour décrire :

Si on se retrouvait mis au pied du mur, acculé dans une situation désespérée sans issue, au sens propre comme au sens figuré, on pourrait faire preuve d'une force surprenante que l'on n'aurait jamais crue possible.

Un incendie, par exemple, pourrait nous permettre de puiser dans notre 火事場の馬鹿力 pour en réchapper.

---

***UPDATE :***

L'expression « l'énergie du désespoir », je me demande s'il s'agit d'une force **extraordinaire** ou simplement de faire tous ses efforts bien qu'étant à bout de force ? Par ailleurs, 火事場の馬鹿力 signifie un **brusque sursaut** d'énergie surhumaine qui ne dure qu'un moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

J'ai déjà rencontré l'expression l'« énergie du désespoir » employée en rapport avec la civilisation japonaise et je me demande si ça ne serait pas la traduction de ce que tu décris par 火事場の馬鹿力.

Par exemple dans [cet article de presse](https://www.franceinter.fr/emissions/la-revue-de-presse/la-revue-de-presse-11-mars-2014) sur les survivants de Fukushima, ou ici après le tsunami, ou dans cet [autre](http://www.liberation.fr/terre/2011/04/22/a-kesennuma-on-doit-renaitre-de-ses-cendres_730790). Ou dans cette phrase tirée d'une [histoire du Japon](https://books.google.fr/books?id=9V1dAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT134&lpg=PT134&dq=japonais%20%22%C3%A9nergie%20du%20d%C3%A9sespoir%22&source=bl&ots=XqPvldDa1b&sig=QHCeHvH8jOzorNtDaNTKyqAiupo&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS-vPw0KHRAhXLCBoKHcRBBRsQ6AEIPzAG#v=onepage&q=japonais%20%22%C3%A9nergie%20du%20d%C3%A9sespoir%22&f=false) :

> La bataille va durer cinq jours. Les hôjô et leurs guerriers se battent avec l'énergie du désespoir : dignitaires du shôgunat, généraux fidèles vaincus, se suicident les uns après les autres.

Est-ce qu'en sens inverse tu emploierais 火事場の馬鹿力 pour traduire « énergie du désespoir dans ces exemples ?

Comment: Hi, Laure. Just updated the post. Merci.

Answer (score 1):

"Kajiba no baka chikara" – litteraly "la force insensée face à l’incendie, la ressource que l’on puise en soi-même lorsqu’on est confronté à la catastrophe"
I think french equivalents are "l’énergie du désespoir" (distress energy) or more "l’énergie de la dernière chance" (last chance enrgy). 
A familiar expression "une souris acculée est prête à mordre un chat" (A cornered mouse is ready to bite a cat).